# OpenJPA merging/persisting is very slow

Tags: java, mysql, performance, openjpa

I use OpenJPA 2.2.0 on WebSphere Application Server 8 with a MySQL 5.0 DB.

I have a list of objects which I want to merge into the DB.

it's like:

```
for (Object ob : list) {
            Long start = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            em = factory.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();

            em.merge(ob);

            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
            Long end = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            Long diff = end - start;
            LOGGER.info("Time: " + diff);
        }
```

When I run this loop I need about 300-600 Milliseconds to merge one object. When I delete the line "em.merge(ob);" then I need "0" Milliseconds to iterate over 1 List Object.

So my question is: What can I do to improve the time to merge one object?

Thanks!

Comment: Turn SQL logging on, see what requests are generated, and see which are taking time and why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try starting the transaction before iteration & then commiting it afterwards within a single transaction. So, basically you are creating a batch which would be merged/persisted on commit.

Also, you can limit the number of objects in a batch to be processed at a time & can explicitly flush the changes into database.

Here, you are initiating a transaction & commiting it in each iteration and also creating/closing entity manager each time, will affect performance for numerous data.

It will be something like below code.

```
em = factory.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
int i = 0;

   for (Object ob : list) {
       Long start = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

       em.merge(ob);

       Long end = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
       Long diff = end - start;
       LOGGER.info("Time: " + diff);

       /*BATCH_SIZE is the number of entities 
            that will be persisted/merged at once */

       if(i%BATCH_SIZE == 0){    
           em.flush();
           em.clear(); 
       }

       i++;
   }

em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

Here, you can also rollback the whole transaction if any of the object fails to persist/merge.

Comment: thank you, I have tryed this before, but the more objects i have the slower the merge will be, I have round about 4000 objects in my list

Comment: @veote As I have already mentioned, you can restrict the number of entities explicitly. Added batch logic to code where you can specify the appropriate batch size(for example take 100, then the changes to 100 entities will be reflected in database immediately at a time), refer code.