# How to persist an Array List of type Entity in JPA

Tags: jpa, arraylist, entity, persist

How to persist an Array List of type Entity in JPA ?

For example, there is an entity called "Table".
I am creating an array list `ArrayList<Table> table = new ArrayList<Table>();`
Trying to persist it using `entityManager.persist(table);` and it did not work. Any solution for this ?

Comment: Can refer http://stackoverflow.com/q/10994139/366964 &  http://stackoverflow.com/q/448181/366964 for batch inserts

Answer (score 8):

```
 EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TDEMSPU");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();


            em.getTransaction().begin(); 

        List<Enquiry> tempEnqList = tempEnqList();
        for (Iterator<Enquiry> it = tempEnqList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Enquiry enquiry = it.next();

            em.persist(enquiry);
            em.flush();
            em.clear();
        }

         em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just iterate over it and persist it one by one

Comment: There are a large number of records I need to persist each time and it is taking too much time to persist each record. So, finding a way to persist whole list at a time.

Comment: @user1855852 - there's actually no way around it - there are no bulk operations for persisting new entites. If you are persisting the entities in a transaction, the provider will generate an optimized SQL for all entities at the end of the transaction.

Comment: Enable batch writing, http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html

Comment: This action can produce an exception for access recurrently to the DataBase.

Comment: @MariaMercedesWyssAlvarez I'm quit sure your exception is not because of this action. If an exception would trigger in a case like saving several items one after another would be a major bug in jpa implementation. what makes you think that your exception is cause by iterating and saving?

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8 you can use `forEach` with a method reference:

```
List<SomeEntity> entities = ...;

entities.forEach(entityManager::persist);
```